# octave in emacs to echo function parameter list in the minibuffer

Tags: matlab, emacs, ide, octave

Just like using lisp interpreter in emacs, I want a similarly function that can do this job under octave in emacs. Anyone already have one?

Comment: I have no experience with the Lisp interpreter in emacs. Can you be more explicit as to what you want?

Comment: What is bad about `octave-send-line`?

Comment: say my input is "(print " then emacs would echo "(print OBJECT &OPTIONAL STREAM)" in the minibuffer to remind you the parameters of the function "print" in lisp.